# What is the difference between throw and throw with arg of caught exception?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

Imagine two similar pieces of code:

```
try {
  [...]
} catch (myErr &err) {
  err.append("More info added to error...");
  throw err;
}
```

and

```
try {
  [...]
} catch (myErr &err) {
  err.append("More info added to error...");
  throw;
}
```

Are these effectively the same or do they differ in some subtle way?  For example, does the first one cause a copy constructor to be run whereas perhaps the second reuses the same object to rethrow it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C++, is there a difference between “throw” and “throw ex”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833982/in-c-is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Depending on how you have arranged your exception hierarchy, re-throwing an exception by naming the exception variable in the throw statement may *slice* the original exception object.

A no-argument throw expression will throw the current exception object preserving its dynamic type, whereas a throw expression with an argument will throw a new exception based on the *static* type of the argument to `throw`.

E.g.

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            throw Derived();
        }
        catch (Base& b)
        {
            std::cout << "Caught a reference to base\n";
            b.print(std::cout);
            throw b;
        }
    }
    catch (Base& b)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught a reference to base\n";
        b.print(std::cout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As written above, the program will output:

```
Caught a reference to base
Derived
Caught a reference to base
Base
```

If the `throw b` is replace with a `throw`, then the outer catch will also catch the originally thrown `Derived` exception. This still holds if the inner class catches the `Base` exception by value instead of by reference - although naturally this would mean that the original exception object cannot be modified, so any changes to `b` would not be reflected in the `Derived` exception caught by the outer block.

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about slicing! Dammit, that's important! Thanks for bringing this up. +1 (Although I think when you wrote "...preserving the original static type..." you meant _dynamic_ type. What's called _dynamic type_, after all, if not the _"original static type"_.) -

Comment: Great answer, I completely forgot about that too.

Comment: I'm happy someone else has run into the _slicing_ problem ;)

Comment: +1 for mentioning slicing. But "...preserving the original static type..." -- Don't you mean dynamic type?

Comment: @sellibitze: Well, it's the original static type of the initial throw expression (which is what I was thinking of originally), or the dynamic type of the originally thrown object which is a more accurate statement. I'll edit.

Answer (score 17):

In the second case according to C++ Standard 15.1/6 copy constructor is not used:

> *A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the exception being handled.  The exception is reactivated with the existing temporary; no new temporary exception object is created.* The exception is no longer considered to be caught; therefore, the value of uncaught_exception() will again be true.

In the first case new exception will be thrown according to 15.1/3:

> A throw-expression initializes a temporary object, called the exception object, the type of which is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand of throw and adjusting
>   the type from “array of T” or “function returning T” to “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T”,
>   respectively. <...> The temporary is used to initialize the variable named in the matching handler (15.3).  The type of the throw-expression shall not be an
>   incomplete type, or a pointer or reference to an incomplete type, other than void*, const void*,
>   volatile void*, or const volatile void*.  Except for these restrictions and the restrictions on
>   type matching mentioned in 15.3, the operand of throw is treated exactly as a function argument in a call
>   (5.2.2) or the operand of a return statement.

In both cases copy constructor is required at throw stage (15.1/5):

> When the thrown object is a class object, and the copy constructor used to initialize the temporary copy is not accessible, the program is ill-formed (even when the temporary object could otherwise be eliminated).
>   Similarly, if the destructor for that object is not accessible, the program is ill-formed (even when the temporary object could otherwise be eliminated).

Comment: Since the copy ctor needs to be accessible for the originally thrown exception anyway, I don't think that's an issue in this case. But yours is still a good answer. +1

Comment: Yes, but in the first case copy c-tor will be used twice.

Comment: It says when the declaration specifies a class type. However in his case it specifies a reference type :) The reference will be bound directly and refer to the exception object. So, we will require a copy ctor only at the point of throwing, not catching in this case (It would make a difference when a base copy constructor is protected, for example).

Comment: I missed that he is using reference type in exception-declaration. Fixed.