# In C++, is there a difference between “throw” and “throw ex”?

Tags: c++, exception

I'd like to ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697216/the-difference-between-try-catch-throw-and-try-catche-throw-e/1833948)), but this time about C++.

What is the difference in C++ between

```
try { /*some code here*/}
catch(MyException& ex)
{ throw ex;} //not just throw
```

and

```
try {  /*some code here*/}
catch(MyException& ex)
{ throw;} //not throw ex
```

Is it just in the stack trace (which in C++ is in any case not a standard as in C# or Java)?

(If it makes any difference, I use MSVS 2008.)

Comment: `throw ex; // out of apartment`

Comment: @sehe my bad, I totally did miss the point.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`throw;` rethrows the same exception object it caught while `throw ex;` throws a new exception. It does not  make a difference other than the performance reasons of creating a new exception object. If you have a exception hierarchy where there some other exception classes derived from `MyException` class and while throwing an exception you have done a `throw DerivedClassException;` it can be caught by the `catch(MyException&)`. Now if you modify this caught exception object and rethrow it using `throw;` the type of exception object will still be `DerivedClassException`. If you do `throw Ex;` the object slicing occurs and the newly thrown exception will be of type `MyException`.

Comment: that depends what ex is. In the example it will be the same object as it is caught by reference (which is the standard way)

Comment: @Naveen, object slicing will not occur if you have caught by reference. If you caught by value the slicing would already have occured although at that point `throw;` would save you because it rethrows the original exception)

Comment: @Phil: This raises an interesting question. GCC slices even when catching by reference...  I wonder what the standard says.

Comment: @Phil: no, read 15.1/3 and 15.1/6. Even if `ex` is a reference, `throw ex;` doesn't (necessarily) throw the referand, it initializes a temporary object using the referand. The temporary may or may not be elided. `throw;`, on the other hand, is specified to re-use the existing temporary.

Comment: @Steve: Suppose it were catch (exception *ex) {throw ex;}, and this was caught by another catch (exception *ex).  As only pointers are represented, one expects no slicing (as the temporary objects would just be temporary pointers).  How is it different with references?

Comment: @Steve, @Managu. Actually you are right. I didn't realise that. That is surprising. I retract my earlier comments

Comment: @Phil: Checked More Effective C++ Item 12, object slicing does occur. Rolled back my answer to the original answer.

Comment: @Managu - throwing/ catching by pointer does work as expected. The difference is that the value of a pointer is the address, but the value of a reference is what it references (even if it's implemented by pointers under the hood)

Comment: @Phil: thanks, that's roughly what I was going to say, but I went and wrote some code to prove it to myself first :-). The difference is that there's such a thing as a pointer object, but no such thing as a reference object. So the temporary intialised by a throw expression can be a pointer, but can't be a reference.

Comment: Dagnammit! I just finger fumbled, and accidentally downvoted this answer. And I can't undo it, I'm being told "vote is too old to change unless the answer is edited". So I edited the answer to add the missing full stop at the end, just so I could vote it back up again. Sorry, Naveen.

Comment: +1 For warning about slicing.
Exceptions are always thrown by value so you need to know their exact type at compile time when you use throw.

Comment: The second sentence of this answer says "It does not make a difference other than the performance...", then the rest of the answer proceeds to explain how it does make a difference.

Answer (score 14):

> #### [[C++ FAQ Lite § 17.9](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9)] What does `throw;` (without an exception object after the `throw` keyword) mean? Where would I use it?
>
> You might see code that looks something like this:
>
> ```
> class MyException {
> public:
>   ...
>   void addInfo(const std::string& info);
>   ...
> };
>
> void f()
> {
>   try {
>     ...
>   }
>   catch (MyException& e) {
>     e.addInfo("f() failed");
>     throw;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, the statement `throw;` means "re-throw the current exception." Here, a function caught an exception (by non-const reference), modified the exception (by adding information to it), and then re-threw the exception. This idiom can be used to implement a simple form of stack-trace, by adding appropriate catch clauses in the important functions of your program.
>
> Another re-throwing idiom is the "exception dispatcher":
>
> ```
> void handleException()
> {
>   try {
>     throw;
>   }
>   catch (MyException& e) {
>     ...code to handle MyException...
>   }
>   catch (YourException& e) {
>     ...code to handle YourException...
>   }
> }
>
> void f()
> {
>   try {
>     ...something that might throw...
>   }
>   catch (...) {
>     handleException();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This idiom allows a single function (`handleException()`) to be re-used to handle exceptions in a number of other functions.
>
> #### [[C++ FAQ Lite § 17.11](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.11)] When I throw this object, how many times will it be copied?
>
> Depends. Might be "zero."
>
> Objects that are thrown must have a publicly accessible copy-constructor. The compiler is allowed to generate code that copies the thrown object any number of times, including zero. However even if the compiler never actually copies the thrown object, it must make sure the exception class's copy constructor exists and is accessible.

(*edited for more clarity on what I thought was obvious...*)

`catch(MyException& ex) { throw ex; }` may copy `ex`, with all the issues that it entails; `catch(MyException& ex) { throw; }` may not.

Comment: Sure, but given that I can choose, in the code above, to do one or the other, what is the difference?

Comment: Great answer, I'll add the comment that we've seen a speed up in our code by moving a large block of exception catching into it's own function.  The speed up was due to making the functions smaller by putting the catch blocks into a function.

Comment: I'd never noticed that "exception dispatcher" idiom before.  Interesting.

Answer (score 14):

If you have an exception hierarchy, `throw ex` can slice your exception, while `throw` won't.  For example:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

struct base 
{ 
  virtual string who() {return "base";} 
}; 

struct derived : public base 
{ 
  string who() {return "derived";} 
}; 

int main() { 
  try { 
    try { 
      throw derived(); // throws a 'derived'
    }  
    catch (base& ex)  
    { 
      throw ex; // slices 'derived' object to be a 'base' object
    } 
  } 
  catch (base& ex) 
  { 
    cout<<ex.who()<<endl; // prints 'base'
  } 
}
```

Change `throw ex` to just `throw`, and you'll get an output of `derived`, which is what you probably expected to get.

Comment: Thanks.  That's surprising.  I wouldn't think that slicing can occur in handling an object by reference.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `throw;` form with `catch(...)` (that is it is the only way to rethrow if you caught using catch(...) ).

Comment: The two have nothing in particular to do with each other.  `throw` means to throw the currently processed exception, and `catch(...)` means to catch any exception.

Comment: My point was that if you caught using catch(...) you cannot rethrow any other way. In the example where an exception is caught by reference, and not modified, there is no real distinction.

Comment: Yes, but I'm really wondering -- given code  as in the sample, where I can choose either one, which should I choose, and why?

Comment: If you just want to rethrow the original exception, use throw;

Answer (score 2):

`throw ex` will make another copy and is not recommend use `throw` only to throw the current exception object.

Comment: That's true, but only if you catch by value - which is not the recommended way anyway

Comment: As in the code sample, I am doing catch-by-reference, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: Hm, a test shows that indeed a copy is made (even if you catch by reference), and slicing happens in the process. Simple **throw** rethrows the exception without slicing, even if the real exception type is a derived class of `MyException`.

Comment: @UncleBens - as I conceded elsewhere, you are right on this. That is surprising

Answer (score 2):

throw can throw a nonstandard exception type that was caught by catch(...) (eg structured exception)

Comment: Wasn't that documented as "unintended side effect in VC6, fixed in VC7"?

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. In this case, though, I know the exception type (MyException). So, is there a difference?

Comment: @peterchen, I hope not. That was darn useful to catch SEH exceptions, clean up, and rethrow them.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, since it sometimes causes confusion, a bare `throw;` outside of an exception-handling context will abort the program.

Comment: Any throw that isn't caught will call `unexpected()`, which will call `terminate()` unless otherwise specified (names from memory).  What's the difference between a bare `throw` and a `throw something` in that case?

Comment: @David, i think Adam means a "throw;" while a handler is not being active. That is, outside of any dynamic exception-handler scope it will call std::terminate (it does not need to occur inside the braces of an exception handler, but such an handler has to have been entered before and not left in the current execution sequence).