# What does it mean to "throw" an empty expression?

Tags: c++, exception

Sometimes in code I see throwing exceptions where the `throw` keyword is used without an expression next to it:

```
throw;
```

What does it mean and when should I use it?

Comment: and [another one...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833982/in-c-is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex) (Fred's comment in this one is priceless, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig funny. I didn't remember it, despite me having trolled that ancient acient-question-trolling comment with my own comment little over a year ago :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty `throw` rethrows the exception.

It can appear only in a `catch` or in a function called from a `catch`.

If an empty `throw` is encountered when a handler is not active, `terminate` will be called.

Answer (score 3):

It rethrows the exception of the currently active `catch` block.

```
try {
  foo();
} catch (...) {
  fix_some_local_thing();
  throw; // keep searching for an error handler
}
```

If there is no currently active `catch` block, it will call `std::terminate`.

Comment: What is an "active catch block"?

Comment: The most recent one entered by exception handling. (You can have a try..catch inside a catch block, and thus have nested exception handling.)

Comment: This terminology is new for me. Also, I have never considered 'catch' blocks active. 'try/catch' blocks, maybe. Then, still, 'active' seems like a strange notion that isn't really consistent with the C++ abstract machine model. I'd opt for 'exception handlers registered in the current callstack', but I'd be interested if you have a source for your/better terminology.

Comment: I believe that "active" is the term used by Standard- at least, I've seen it many times before.

Comment: "current exception object", or "currently handled exception".

Comment: R.MartinhoFernandes That's about the exception, not the handler. @DeadMG Thanks!

Comment: I used whatever word came to mind, not any standard terminology.

Comment: @sehe the handler doesn't matter. The standard describes the functionality in terms of the exception. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fbd004ed6b18aacfdbd1f84a235728e9-00cd033b7ad7a487b1892674bc8212f7

Answer (score 1):

It's a rethrow of the current exception.

This doesn't alter the current exception, effectively just resuming the stack-unwinding after doing the actions in your catch{} block.

Quoting the standard: **§ 15.1 ad 8** `[except.throw]`

> A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the currently handled exception (15.3). ***The exception is reactivated with the existing temporary; no new temporary exception object is created.*** The exception is ***no longer considered to be caught***; therefore, the value of ***`std::uncaught_exception()` will again be true***.
>
> Example: code that must be executed because of an exception yet cannot completely handle the exception can be written like this:
>
> ```
> try {
> // ...
> } catch (...) { // catch all exceptions
> // respond (partially) to exception
> throw; // pass the exception to some
> // other handler
> }
> ```

Comment: added standards quote :/

Answer (score 1):

In a function declaration, it means that the function won't throw any exception.

In a `catch` block, it re-throws the caught exception, e.g.

```
try {
   throw "exception";
catch ( ... ) {
   std::cout << "caught exception";
   throw; // Will rethrow the const char* exception
}
```

Comment: So it will go back to the `try` block?

Comment: No, it throws the exception to the next outer `try` block. It can be used to react on an exception locally, but also passing the exception to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

It's used inside a `catch` block to rethrow the current exception.