# ex.what() changes in nested try-catch

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have a nested try-catch code like below:

```
void A()
{
    try
    {
        //Code like A = string(NULL) that throws an exception
    }
    catch(std::exception& ex)
    {
        cout<<"in A : " << ex.what();
        throw ex;
    }
}

void B()
{
   try
   {
       A();
   }
   catch(std::exception& ex)
   {
       cout<<"in B : " << ex.what();
   }
}
```

After running this I got this result:

```
in A: basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
in B: std::exception
```

As you can see, `ex.what()` works OK in function A and tell me the correct description, but in B `ex.what()` tells me just `std::exception`. Why does this happen?

Am I throwing something different or wrong in the catch clause of function A? How do I throw a nested exception so that I can get the exact exception description in B?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481612/what-is-the-difference-between-throw-and-throw-with-arg-of-caught-exception, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833982/in-c-is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Replace `throw ex;` with `throw;`.

Doing the latter will re-throw the exception `ex`, *by reference*, so obviating the hazards in attempting to make a value copy: see [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

(Note that you *are* allowed to *modify* `ex` even if you write `throw`).

Comment: with all respect to @StoryTeller answer, i accept yours because of extra link and your point at the end.

Comment: Nitpick, but I assume you mean `throw;`, as (AFAIK) `throw` on its own isn't valid.

Answer (score 32):

You are throwing a copy of the exception `ex` in `A`. Which causes object slicing that turns the concrete exception into `std::exception`.

To rethrow the actual exception you caught polymorphically, use the `throw;` statement.

It's worth keeping in mind what Scott Meyers says in his book. You throw by value, and should catch by reference.

Answer (score 7):

You're [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) the original exception object, try with

```
try {
  throw std::runtime_error("Hello world");
}
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
  cout << "in A : " << ex.what();
  throw; // Rethrows the original exception - no copy or slicing
  ^^^^^^
}
```